# Locating the O2 sensors and the cat along the exhaust

Tags: exhaust, o2-sensor, catalytic-converter

I gather that the **upstream** O2 sensor is the one right in the center of this picture. I also gather that the catalytic converter (the "cat") is the bulbous part of the exhaust right behind this sensor.

[image: upstream]

Question 1: Does the cat consist of just this one part or does it include the second 'bulb' in the exhaust that appears in this second picture?

[image: midstream]

Question 2: This third picture shows the section closest to the tail pipe. I can't spot the **downstream** O2 sensor. Can you suggest where I should be looking?

[image: downstream]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picture 1 is the downstream 02 sensor. Upstream is located on the exhaust manifold.
Picture 1 contains both convertors.

Picture 2 is the exhaust resonator.

Comment: Ha! I was just typing that out and you beat me to it. +1 :o)

Comment: Let me just confirm. So the cat *does* consist of two parts, and the downstream O2 is located *between* the two parts. This means that measuring whether the cat is doing its job reflects only that the first part is active. It doesn't reflect whether the second part (downstream) is working properly. Is that right?

Comment: @Calaf correct.

Comment: @Calaf: By "second part", you mean the resonator, right? A resonator doesn't really play an important role in emissions. It's primary role is to limit or adjust the exhaust note in addition to the mufflers.

Comment: @Ellesedil he's talking about the second converter after the primary  converter and downstream sensor.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Most cats are actually two converters in one lump; one for CO/HC; one for NOx. If space is an issue, they can separate them like this without issue and it will still function as it was designed. IIRC, the NOx redux portion won't change the readings which the after cat O2 senses, thus why the sensor is between the two. The front one will be the CO/HC redux portion.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Quite a bit different than my Subaru, then. I have just a single cat in my j/downpipe immediately after my turbo. That's why I was confused by the different parts.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Completely understand. Most are just one lump, so I was confused before I failed emissions on NOx using a two-way converter. Figured it out and bought a three-way converter for replacement.

Comment: @Ellesedil My only clue that it consists of two parts is that the images of the parts sold (for example: http://www.amazon.com/Walker-53717-Certified-Catalytic-Converter/dp/B0049JD2JY/) consist of two parts. Thanks, Paulster2, for the clarification. It makes perfect sense why the sensor is between the two parts rather than downstream the second.